# how to search any keyword from string using jfce AutoCompleteField

Tags: swt, jface

I have swt text where in I have written like "new AutoCompleteField (textSearch,new TextContentProvider(), searchList); it works but it finds the strings start with expression. I want to create my own proposal provider where i can write something if my string contains any keyword, i should get autoComplete popup.

Comment: What do you mean by 'contains any keyword'? Show us some examples of what should happen.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for example i have some products stored in String[] prodList = new String []{"clothes","watches","shoes","mobile",home appliance"}; now let's say if i search "obi" or "appli" , it should give me a string which contains such typed keywords​. so my AutoComplete result would be "mobile" or "home appliance". At the moment, it give me a result starting with typed start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the existing `AutoCompleteField` for this since you need to change the content proposal provider.

A suitable `IContentProposalProvider` would be something like:

```java
public class AnyPositionContentProposalProvider implements IContentProposalProvider
{
  private final String [] proposals;

  public AnyPositionContentProposalProvider(String [] theProposals)
  {
    proposals = theProposals;
  }

  @Override
  public IContentProposal [] getProposals(String contents, int position)
  {
    List<IContentProposal> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String proposal : proposals) {
       if (proposal.contains(contents)) {
         result.add(new ContentProposal(proposal));
       }
    }

    return result.toArray(new IContentProposal [result.size()]);
  }
}
```

The following methods set this up to work like `AutoCompleteField`:

```java
// Installs on a Text control
public static void installAnyPositionMatch(Text control, String [] proposals)
{
  installAnyPositionMatch(control, new TextContentAdapter(), proposals);
}

// Install on any control with a content adapter
public static void installAnyPositionMatch(Control control, IControlContentAdapter controlContentAdapter, String [] proposals)
{
  IContentProposalProvider proposalProvider = new AnyPositionContentProposalProvider(proposals);

  ContentProposalAdapter adapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(control, controlContentAdapter, proposalProvider, null, null);
  adapter.setPropagateKeys(true);
  adapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
}
```